# about jquery-validation-1.11.1 plug in

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i have used "jquery-validation-1.11.1 plug in" to check data validation for register form. it is the good and useful plug-in. complete code is here.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data validation with jquery plug-in</title>
    <style>
        label{
            display:block;
            color: #555;

            margin-left:500px;
        }
        label.error{
            color: #900;
            font-style: Italic;
        }
        input{

            margin-left:500px;
        }
        textarea{
            margin-left:500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="comment" action="">
        <p>
            <label for="cname">Name(required, at least 2 characters)</label>
            <input id="cname" name="name">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="cemail">Name(required)</label>
            <input id="cemail" name="email" type="email">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="curl">URL(optional)</label>
            <input id="curl" name="url" type="url">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="comment">Your comment(required)</label>
            <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Click">
        </p>
    </form>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#comment").validate({
                rules:{
                    name:{
                        "required":true,
                        "min":2
                    },
                    email:{
                        "required":true,
                        "email":true
                    },
                    comment:{
                        "required":true
                    }
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

i want to check validation when click "submit button" only. But now my problem is when i click any button, do data validation. how can i fix it?

Comment: Please generate more accurate question titles and try to reformat your question, because it can be understood in many ways. Also include example code of what you've tried / what you're doing.

Comment: Why are you using a form submit button to go to the home page? Use a regular anchor link.

Comment: i have produced accurate and complete code example. please check it and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules:{
         name:{
             "required":true,
             "min":2
         },
         email:{
             "required":true,
             "email":true
         },
         comment:{
             "required":true
         }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('form submitted');
        return false;
    }
});

$('#register').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
$('#home-page-submit').on('click', function () {
    // home page called
    alert('form cancelled');
    location.href='home.html';
    return false;
});
```

Change your `submit buttons` like,

```
    <p>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="submit" id="register">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Click" id="home-page-submit">
    </p>
 </form>
```

**Also** why are you making `2 submit buttons` you can just create a `simple button` for `home-page` like

```
<input type="button" value="Go to home page" 
                 onclick="window.location.href='home.html'" />
```